# Spellchecker on DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, spell-checking

Good day. I'm still a junior programmer and recently started coding in WPF. I have a datagrid where I generate my own columns. In one specific column, a DataGridTextColumn, I have to apply a spell check (the user can add comments to this field). But I can't manage to do this. I have tried applying a style but no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated! Here is the coding for the column:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clValueComment" Binding="{Binding CommentColumn, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="ROOTCAUSE OR COMMENT" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" Style="{StaticResource Spell}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding valueTypeID}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Label IsEnabled="False"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with some more of the Styling options, I found a solution that seems to be working. I'll post it as an answer for someone who might come across the same requirement. The XAML coding that did the trick is:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: thanks, helped me out!  For anyone else that comes across this, it only works (as described) when editing the text, it wont show errors when in regular view-mode.